# Find the button object that called the event with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to bind an event to a few buttons...

```
$(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick());
```

In the function `stageButtonClick()`, I want to get the object of the calling button, but I cannot use `$(this)` inside the `stageButtonClick` function, it doesn't return anything for me.

Also, please don't suggest the inline function usage

```
$(".numField").bind("click", function() {...})
```

I would like to learn how to do it this way.

Comment: Can you pass `$(this)` to the function `stageButtonClick($(this))`?

Comment: Does `stageButtonClick()` return a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick());
                       don't use parenthesis ^^
```

Don't use parenthesis when assigning a named function because it will call the function and assign the result instead.

This works:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gSzjn/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick);

});

function stageButtonClick()
{
     alert( $(this).attr("id") );  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do things in a very un-jQuery way.  Even if you don't want the entire function inline you could make your life much easier by doing something like this:

```
$(".numField").bind("click", function() {
    stageButtonClick(this); // or stageButtonClick($(this)) if you want to pass jQuery selector
});
```

Here you simply pass the clicked DOM element to your `stageButtonClick()` function.

Also, if you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher, you should really use `on()` instead of `bind()`.

Comment: I see, because it is enclosed in the function, then using $(this) will send the specific button's object instead of the document object... I tried this without enclosing it in a function like this and $(this) gave me the document object instead. Good post; informative.

Answer (score 1):

At first, `$(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick());` will not work because `stageButtonClick()` return the result of the `stageButtonClick` function, not the function itself

Second, an `event` objet is passed to the called function with a `target` and `currentTarget` element. Normaly, the `event.currentTarget` will be `.numField`.

So, try with `$(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick);` and you could normally use `$(this)` or `$(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely right! I found my error now. Also, I tried using $(event.currentTarget), but that didn't seem to work. To be more specific, in the function I put "$(event.currentTarget).text()" yielded nothing, while "$(this).text()" worked well... I would like to learn about the event.currentTarget object

Answer (score 1):

If thats the case you can use the `event object`

```
$(".numField").bind("click", stageButtonClick);

function stageButtonClick(e){
   // You can just use 
         **this**
   OR
       **$(e.target)**
}
```

Also bind the event using `.on()` instead of `.bind()` as the later has been **superseeded** by the former.

```
$(".numField").on("click", stageButtonClick);
```