# Getting the sender of an event?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

How can I get the sender of an onSubmit event in *any* browser? Or at least in FF and IE?
Esp. as `event.srcElement`in IE seems to be the target?
Well, isn't there anything like `explicitOriginaltarget` in browsers other than FF?

I'm looking for any solution in *pure* javascript, no JQuery.

What I want to do:
I've got a form. And depending on the sender I want to do differnt actions in the `onSubmit(event)` routine.

What I got in my init function:

```
var top_most_form = document.getElementById("upper_menu_form");
top_most_form.onsubmit=function(event){

var target = <apparently magical things have to happen here>;

if ("upper_menu_form" == target.id) {
  AddSpinner();
  AddStarttimeToForm();
  AddThruputToUpperForm();
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the button object that called the event with jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887252/find-the-button-object-that-called-the-event-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: By "depending on the sender", do you mean you have multiple forms with a shared handler function, or you have one form with multiple submit buttons?

Comment: Can/are you willing to use JQuery? Could also be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351660/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-sender-input-element-from-keyup-event

Comment: No JQuery :(
I've got one form with a submit button and some js functions, that call submit()

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831942/can-i-find-out-from-a-javascript-method-who-which-dom-element-called-me

Comment: Are you bubbling events at all? Or do you want, say, the "clicked" element?

Comment: What is "to bubble events? I want the element, that has been clicked to submit the form.

Comment: The submit event will be fired by the form element itself, so you'll have a hard time finding the input that triggered it. Listening for clicks and then triggering the submit yourself should work though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crossbrowser equivalent of explicitOriginalTarget event parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179826/crossbrowser-equivalent-of-explicitoriginaltarget-event-parameter)

Comment: Yeah, but this question is more than 5 years old.

Answer (score 7):

Here you have a function. You just need to evaluate wich parameter is present in your event object

```
function getTarget(e){
  e=e||window.event;
  return (e.target||e.srcElement);
};
```

See: [jQuery - how to determine which link was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862764/jquery-how-to-determine-which-link-was-clicked)

Comment: nope, the srcElement is -unfortunately- not the sender but the target :(

Comment: what about e.originalEvent || e.originalTarget; ?